# Angular ng-show does not reflect value of condition

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular template with a form for user data. Some fields like name and address only show if the user needs an invoice:

```
<div class="personal-details" ng-show="showInvoiceFields()">
    <!-- input fields here... -->
</div>
```

I have a function `showInvoiceFields()` in the scope that returns true if the current user has "invoice role" or if the product requires an invoice.

```
  $scope['showInvoiceFields'] = function () {
    console.log('hasInvoiceRole: ' + $scope['hasInvoiceRole']);
    console.log('product:');
    console.log($scope['product']);
    return $scope['hasInvoiceRole'] || $scope['product'].needsInvoice;
  };
```

That part of the form is initially hidden until a product is selected from a dropdown. Initially, I read this in the console because the user doesn't have invoice role:

```
hasInvoiceRole: false
product needs invoice:
undefined
undefined
```

When I select a product that requires invoice, I read:

```
hasInvoiceRole: false
product needs invoice:
{... a ver big object..., needsInvoice: true, ...}
```

However the fields don't show. This only happens in production. Maybe there is something specific about the minified code that causes the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue in my code. The culprit lies here:

```
$scope['product'].needsInvoice
```

When angular minifies the code, it probably renames all variables, including "needsInvoice". To fix it, I simply changed this line to:

```
$scope['product']['needsInvoice']
```